# Understanding "Markov Property" in Simple Terms?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

**I have been trying to understand how a "Semi Markov Chain/Process" differs from a standard "Markov Chain/Process ".**

Doing some reading online, as the name implies - it seems like the difference between these two concepts is related to the **"Markov Property"** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property). As I understand, the Markov Property states that "future states visited by the chain/process only depends on the current state and does not depend on previous states visited by the chain/process.

However, one subtlety I am starting to realize (I am not sure if this is correct) is that the Markov Property also implies that the "time spent in the current state does not influence the time at which the transition to the next state will be made".

**With this being said - is the above point what separates a "Semi Markov Chain/Process" from a standard "Markov Chain Process"?**

That is, in a Semi Markov Chain/Process, the time spent in the current state can indeed influence the time at which the next transition will be made - thus allowing Semi Markov Chains/Processes to model real-world situations in which future transitions depend on the time spent in the current state (e.g. the longer you remain in an unemployed state, the less likely you are to leave the unemployed state), which would be unsuitable for standard Markov Chains/Processes (e.g. Homogenous Continuous Markov Chains, Inhomogeneous Markov Chains)?

Is this assertion correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your assertion and understanding are correct.

Check out this [preview of a textbook chapter](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-2367-3_8). Basically, the definition of a Markov chain always leads to the same distribution for how long we spend in a given state before moving on. Semi-Markov chains are introduced specifically to change that part of the definition, so that they can do a better job of modelling situations where time spent in a state DOES influence the distribution of how much longer we'll spend before leaving.

Your example about unemployment is a perfectly reasonable example of a situation where you might want to use a SMP instead of a MP.

Comment: @ David Clyde: Thank you so much for your answer! Do you know anything about modelling Markov Chains? I posted a question here - can you please check it out? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594033/markov-chains-from-theory-to-application  Thanks!

Comment: I posted a response on that other question too.

Comment: @ David Clyde: Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement the previous answer: it is indeed the case that SMP extends CTMC by allowing the residence time in each state to be general. However, CTMC are still very powerful, as you can approximate any distribution as far as you add enough states.

For instance, you can approximate a deterministic distribution by adding $N$ states in a row, where the residence time in each state is $1/N$.  The residence time in this set of states will get closer and closer to a deterministic distribution, equal 1, as $N$ goes to infinity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-type_distribution

The set of phase-type distributions is dense in the field of all positive-valued distributions, that is, it can be used to approximate any positive-valued distribution.

Therefore, given the simplicity of CTMC, sometimes it is better to work with it as opposed to relying on more powerful (and complex) models. Sometimes CTMC suffices to get good approximations for the problems at hand, where you just want to know some trends.

Comment: @ Daniel S. : Thank you so much for your answer again!